# Please give shortcut key to import package in ASP .Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please somebody tell shortcut to import packages in .Net.in spring boot we can use ctrl+1 for that.

Comment: There isn't one by default, but feel free to customise your keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: For opening package manager console you can try ALT + T + N and then pressing enter. But you can easily find this kind of information by searching the internet.

Answer (score 0):

select the error which is asking to import package
then over there use shortcut ctrl + . then enter